# Как не забивать оперативную память в Android?

Tags: android, память

Есть приложение, в нем есть много различных Activity, в свою очередь в них есть картинки. Когда я запускал приложение и в MemoryMonitor смотрел на использование памяти, я увидел, что при открытии одного Activity память загружается, примерно на 10 мб, и так получается, что те Activity, с которых я перешел, они содержатся в памяти, и при повторном их открытии уже не грузит память.

Но можно ли сделать так, чтобы при переходе на другую активность память чистилась или что-то в этом роде? Может, вопрос слишком  абстрактный, но все же.

Comment: В `onPause`/`onStop` методах у `Activity` чистите ресурсы, а потом востанавливается в `onResume`/`onStart`

Comment: А как чистить? Или есть литература, где это описано? Буду очень благодарен.

Comment: не нужно чистить. Система сама очистит память тогда, когда ей это потребуется.

Comment: Если бы она это делала,  я бы не писал сюда, из-за этой проблемы у меня частенько вылетает с надписью OutOfMemory

Comment: вот вам список литературы, который вы должны прочитать [тык][1], чтобы не задавать таких вопросов ;)
[1]: http://habrahabr.ru/post/153373/

Comment: @alex11, значит вы делаете что-то ужасное. Что-то, что вы от нас скрываете.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На мой взгляд, основные поедатели памяти - это ImageView. Один 3 мб шный png -шник может занимать 20 мб оперативы. Поэтому надо прежде всего с ними быть аккуратнее + они не всегда уничтожаются при выходе из активити, лучше их чистить ручками.

А вообще жрать по 100 мб оперативы для запущенной во весь экран проге (т.е. не фоновой) вполне нормально (в этом плане далвик вполне похож на jvm :))

Comment: Можно поподробней, как их руками "уничтожать"? Буду очень благодарен.

Comment: @alex11 как-то так:
ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.my_image);
Drawable drawable = imageView.getDrawable();
if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
    BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) drawable;
    Bitmap bitmap = bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
    bitmap.recycle();
}

Comment: png, jpeg, разницы для нет. Если одинаковое разрешение - одинаковое количество памяти расходуется

Comment: @danpetruk А если картинок много, то для каждой прописывать?

Comment: @alex11 можно ещё system.gc() вызвать

Comment: @danpetruk а gc() может и не запустится

Answer (score 4):

Не используйте статические поля.
Не делайте ссылок на активити, фрагменты.
Будьте осторожны с передачей ссылок на активити в потоки.
Почитайте на досуге [статью](http://habrahabr.ru/company/sebbia/blog/243537/).

Answer (score 3):

Не согласен насчёт очистки в onPause!!! Категорически!!! Начнём с того, что ресурсы должны чистится в методе onDestroy службы, ибо сказано - все тяжеловесные задачи должны выполнятся в отдельных потоках. А для андроида есть удобная вещь для этих целей - служба. А если держать что-то тяжелое в активити и закрывать ресурсы в onPause/onStop (и открывать их заново при onResume/onStart), то это будет происходить при каждом перевороте экрана и при сворачивании активити на задний план.

ЗЗЫ Из-за чего вылетал OOM error? У меня такое было только при засирании памяти огромными картинками 2000 Х 2000 разрешением. Пришлось писать стек специальный и вызывать recycle() для bitmap объектов.

Comment: При поворотах Activity в любом случае пересоздаётся

Comment: ну и ? очень хорошо создавать ресурс заново каждый раз и убивать его ? а если для создания нужно подключится к серверу, отстоять очередь , пождаться ответа... ? что тогда ? при каждом повороте заново будем ?

Comment: Для этого кеш придумали.